# Rails 5: redirect wildcards except mentioned ones in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got this in my routes.rb

```
constraints SubdomainConstraint do
  scope '/', controller: :hub_categories do
    get '/', to: 'hub_categories#index'
    get 'list', to: 'hub_categories#list'

    post 'documents', to: 'hub_categories#create'
    delete 'documents/:id', to: 'hub_categories#destroy'
    get 'documents/:id/request', to: 'hub_categories#request'
    get 'documents/:id/result', to: 'hub_categories#result'
    get 'documents/:id/word', to: 'hub_categories#word'
  end

  root to: 'hub_categories#index'
end
```

Outside this constraint I've got a lot more routes, like `/documents` and the like. How can I match anything except those routes inside the constraint (including, let's say, `get 'documents'`) to `'hub_categories#index'`?

All my attempts, like `match '*', to: 'hub_categories#index', via: :all` in the constraint block itself, wind up with this error:

> ruby /Users/cdrum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@aplus/bin/rspec(51938,0x7fff9ee53340) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fef03d21210: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
>   set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

**Off-topic update**

That error was owing to a corrupt RVM install, so if you're getting that run `rvm implode` then reinstall RVM, then Ruby, then your gems.

Comment: I think instead of just having it match `*`, you need to get it to match to `*path`. It's hard to test this myself as you're using a subdomain constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this at the bottom of the `SubdomainConstraint` block did the trick:

```
get '*path', to: 'hub_categories#index'
```

Rails 5 deprecated `match`, and my error was due to a corrupt RVM install.